# Facebook Like Box not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox, facebook-likebox

For some reason the Facebook Like Box is not showing up on Firefox. It's working perfectly on other browsers.

Here's the site.
http://www.rochesternypoker.com/

The Like Box is in the left column.

No other code is interfering with it. I tried it on a blank page and it works great in Chrome, but still now showing up in Firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nice trick to get more likes for the page!!

Comment: It's seriously not working for me. I've tried on multiple computers. Is it showing up fine for you?

Comment: Yes. it is showing up properly. Are you logged in to Facebook in Firefox?

Comment: No I wasn't logged into Facebook in Firefox. I did just try logging in and it showed up. Any idea why it's only showing up when logged in?

Comment: I guess that is the desired behavior by Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please right click on the browser, select Inspect Element, select console tab and refresh the page and check if any error is shown in console when that page is used for like box?

Did s/he edit the age restriction? If yes, please ask him/her to select Anyone 13+ for the page.

Fix this problem first. I tried using chrome and got some errors please check it out.

If not then the facebook page might have to change country restrictions. If you don't see the box on a certain browser check to make sure you are logged into facebook on that browser.

[This article explains what might possibly be your problem.]
(http://www.andreavahl.com/facebook/why-your-facebook-like-box-is-not-showing-up.php)

Answer (score 0):

This could be down to browser addons or extensions and not your code. I've saw it in the past. If you have ad blocker add on or avast anti virus browser extension (possible other anti virus extensions too) then check the settings there. both avast and ad blocker plus will block a lot of social links as standard, go to settings and choose not to block social media. It will be an extension you have on chrome, but not on firefox.